# What are these white areas of coronary thrombosis?

Tags: pathology, red-blood-cell, pathogenesis

Please, see the picture where the areas (1,2,3) look little yellow:

[image]

I think these areas are fat, platelets and/or air.
I think 3 is fat/platelets while 1 is air/platelets.
There also exists white thrombosis, which can explain something here.
However, I do not it is that because those white areas do not contain thrombocytes or leucocytes (not sure, since I have no more closer picture; probably you can see it from this).

I think at the moment that these white areas are endothelium-lined spaces.
However, I am not sure about (3).

**What can these three areas be in the coronary thrombosis?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low density lipoproteins can be taken up by the macrophages under a number of circumstances (typically high circulating levels is the most important). These macrophages are called foam cells. The macrophage can then die and deposit this cholesterol and fatty material onto a vessel wall in the context of atherosclerosis. Additionally tissue damage as a result of release of damaging chemicals from the macrophage can induce an inflammatory response recruiting more macrophages (worsening the problem in a cyclical manner) and result in fibrosis and platelet activation. I think this would cause the white stuff you point to.

In summary I think you're right, it's a combination of fat, cholesterol, fibrotic tissue and platelets. 3 is more likely macrophages and platelets whilst 1 and 2 are more likely a combination of all the above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I completely missed the term "foam cells".